# How to call std::function after move to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, std-function

I am stuck on how to call a std::function that has been moved into a shared_ptr…

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using func_type = std::function<int()>;

int main(int, char*[])
{   
    func_type func = [] () { return 42; };
    std::cout << func() << "\n"; // -> 42
    auto sp_func = std::make_shared<func_type>(std::move(func));
    // how do we now call the function?
}
```

I'd be grateful for any (smart) pointers in the right direction.

Comment: `(*sp_func)()`.

Comment: @Quentin : Oh jeez, thanks very much - I was an asterisk at the outside of the left parenthesis away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've just created a (smart) pointer that points to your function. 
All you have to do to access the object is to *dereference* that pointer, then you get your function back.

In this case you should just use `(*sp_func)()`.

*Notes:*

1. Make sure you parenthesize so you dereference the pointer before trying to call the function; the call operator has a higher precedence than the dereference one.
2. You should never rely on a moved object again. That is, never in your code try to call `func()` directly after that move. This is *undefined behavior*. You don't really know the state of a moved object.

Comment: Or `sp_func->operator()()`.  Second, your "2" is over broad; sometimes you do know the state of a moved object, sometimes you don't.  In`std` often you don't, as the standard explicltly states you don't.  On the other hand, I know the state of `a` after `int a=7; int b=std::move(a);` -- it is guaranteed by the standard to be 7.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Humm, thanks for adding to the answer, I didn't know about your last point. About the first, technically it's right, however it is quite unusual to call an operator explicitly like this (as in `operator+(a,b)`), and it also makes your code way more difficult to understand, that's the reason I omitted it. Thanks!